# Split a string in VB.NET by ("||"), when the string have | that need to go too

Tags: vb.net, split

I have a string that need a clean,

the way the program do it is by take the phrases that need to be removed, split them, and replace each with " ".

the phrases split char is ("||") `LocationStopPhrases.Split(CChar("||"))`, and i cant change that for now.

the problem is that i have the phrase `|  CO-Lakewood` that need to be removed, so the split brake it to array like this: `["", "CO-Lakewood"]`.

is there a way (like escape in regex) so the single pipe will be in the array, so it will look like this: `["|", "CO-Lakewood"]`?

just to be clear, i cant change the code, i can only set the phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.Split(CChar("||"))` is not doing what you intend because `CChar("||")` is `|`.

What you need is the overload of [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_) which allows you to split on a string rather than a character:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim LocationStopPhrases = "hello||world|||  CO-Lakewood"
        Dim p = LocationStopPhrases.Split({"||"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(vbCrLf, p))
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

outputs:

```
hello
world
|  CO-Lakewood
```

You can then deal with the single | as needed; for example,

```
"|  CO-Lakewood".Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

would give `["|", "CO-Lakewood"]`.

Of course, if `world|` was the intended part, then a different solution would be needed.

Comment: Thanks, i tried to avoid fix very old code, but i did it eventually.

I replaced:

`Split(CChar("||"))` 

with

`Split({"||"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

and it fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can split at single `|` and remove the empty entries

```
Dim parts = input.Split(New Char() { "|"c }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

The result is that the input will be split at `||` as well as at `|`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload of String.Split that takes a string array and StringSplitOptions.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim s = "The quick || brown fox | jumped over || the lazy dogs."
    Dim SplitBy = {"||", "fox"}
    Dim SplitString = s.Split(SplitBy, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    For Each s In SplitString
        Debug.Print(s)
    Next
    'Output
    'The quick 
    ' brown
    ' | jumped over 
    ' the Lazy dogs.
End Sub
```